# how to load json in cibonfire?

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, bonfire

i have this controller from penjualan_resep module

```
public function load_data_mahasiswa() {
 $term = $_POST['parent_id'];
$response = array();
$mahasiswa = $this->mahasiswa_model->find_by('nim', $term); //load data from mahasiswa model
if ($mahasiswa) {
    $response[] = $mahasiswa;
}else{
    $response['error'] = 'Data Kosong';
}
echo json_encode($response); //convert to json
}
```

and this is my view

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nim").keyup(function() {
        var nisp = $('#nim').val();
        $.post('<?php echo site_url(SITE_AREA.'/content/penjualan_resep/load_data_mahasiswa');?>', //load data using json
                {parent_id: nisp},
        function(data) {
            $('#nama_pasien').val(data[0].nama); //load from database
        }, 'json'
                );
    });
});
```

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NIM</td>
                            <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="nim" id="nim"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nama</td>
                            <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama_pasien"></td>
                        </tr>
</table>
```

i want to autofill form "Nama", when i fill form "NIM" using json, but it can't? how to solve it? i'm using cibonfire framework(base on codeigniter).

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: json can't load  when i fill "NIM" form. Is cibonfire not recognize $term = $_POST['parent_id']; ?

Comment: what is the value of `$mahasiswa` from model??

Comment: this is my sql table CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bf_mahasiswa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `kdsem` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `nim` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tahun_masuk` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `nama` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `progdi` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `fakultas` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `fak_progdi` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=23901 ;

Comment: can u add model code `find_by`??

Comment: this is the value 
INSERT INTO `bf_mahasiswa` (`id`, `recid`, `kdsem`, `nim`, `tahun_masuk`, `nama`, `progdi`, `fakultas`, `fak_progdi`) VALUES
(1, '651118', '20151', 'A210090004', 2009, 'ANANG CANDRA ADITYA PURYANTO', 'Pend. Akuntansi', 'KIP', 'KIP / Pend. Akuntansi'),
(2, '629063', '20151', 'A210090021', 2009, 'PRIA TITIS WASKHITT0 AJI', 'Pend. Akuntansi', 'KIP', 'KIP / Pend. Akuntansi'),
(3, '628644', '20151', 'A210090052', 2009, 'BUDIYANTO', 'Pend. Akuntansi', 'KIP', 'KIP / Pend. Akuntansi'),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97585/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-debujang).

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse json since you are using `$.post`.

```
 var data1 = $.parseJSON(data);
 alert(data1[0].nama)
 $('#nama_pasien').val(data1[0].nama); //load from database
```